# Has anyone ever gone to arbitration against Airbnb for not following their own TOS?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, breach-of-contract

I feel Airbnb has violated their own TOS with their long term cancelation policy posted in another section of their site. Because this section changes frequently, I use their TOS as the legally binding contract between us - as also stated in their TOS. Looks like we're going to go to arbitration, has anyone ever gone against Airbnb pro se and won?

Comment: I wouldn't VTC your post, but you should modify it to make it answerable. It is very unlikely that someone or someone's acquaintances (1) has proceeded, let alone *pro se*, against the company, (2) prevailed in the proceedings, and (3) happens to be on LawSE so as to share that knowledge. Even if these conditions are met, it would be irrelevant to the particulars of *your* matter. Instead, you might want to provide details about the TOS at issue as well as the violation(s) for which you intend to go to arbitration.

Comment: A key difficulty is that in most cases there is no public record of arbitration proceedings unless it produces an award that a party brings suit in, in court, to enforce, after prevailing that the losing party doesn't just agree to pay. The privacy afforded by this process is one of several reasons that firms like to use arbitration in consumer disputes.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

[This](https://community.withairbnb.com/t5/Hosting/My-Arbitration-Experience/td-p/640858) guy says he did. Of course, the case settled without an arbitrator’s decision but it is technically a fought and won arbitration.

Since arbitrations are private, we will only know about them if one of the parties tells us.